# Lightning controller

Tags: lightning-design-system

I have created a basic lightning page to insert account record. It is working fine I can insert a record and can see records are getting created into the database but I require that once I click submit button to insert a record it should navigate to the created record. It is not navigating as aspected. Please see my code below:

Helper:

```
({  
   createAccount : function(component, Account) {
    console.log('inside helper');
    var action = component.get("c.saveAccount");
    console.log('after method called ');
    action.setParams({
        "Account": Account 
    });
action.setCallback(this, function(response){
    var state = response.getState();
    if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
        var accounts = component.get("v.accounts"); 
        accounts.push(response.getReturnValue());
        component.set("v.accounts", accounts);  
    }
});
$A.enqueueAction(action); 
},
```

})

Apex code:

```
public class NewAccountHandler {
@AuraEnabled
public static Account saveAccount(Account Account) { 
    system.debug('***--' + Account);
    upsert Account;
    system.debug('***--1' + Account);
    return Account;
}
```

}

Please help me in this how to navigate to the created record page. Its not moving from this page.[image]

Comment: Is that 'v.accounts' attribute of type Account or List of Accounts?

Answer (score 1):

It's not navigating to the record page, because you don't have that logic implemented in your code. To be able to navigate to a particular record id, you can use **force:navigateToSObject**

> Navigates to an sObject record specified by recordId.
>   To display the record view, set the record ID on the recordId attribute and fire the event.

In your `createAccount` function in the controller, you need to capture the id of the record created and use this event to be able to redirect it to the details page. You can find more on this event on the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToSObject.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Store the response value (which should be an Account object) and then call a `force:navigateToSObject` event.

```
var createdAccount = response.getReturnValue();
var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
navEvt.setParams({
  "recordId": createdAccount.Id
});
navEvt.fire();
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToSObject.htm